# Более одного пункта меню верхнего уровня в chrome.contextMenus. Как?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension, extension

Кто нибудь знает о возможности добавления нескольких пунктов меню в контекстное меню расширения **chrome**?
Очень долго переходить в подменю :(

Дело в том, что при добавлении нескольких пунктов они группируются. Опции в [chrome.contextMenus.create](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/contextMenus/#method-create) я такой не нашел.

Может быть какой хак или флаг браузера?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD: Все сайты за сутки перерыл и ничего не нашел :( Пришлось ниже...

Comment: Может нужно указать разные `id`?

Comment: @OliverPatterson я пробовал даже `parentId=null`, ничего не помогает. А ид там одинаковые и нельзя указать, они вызовут ошибку. По дефолту устанавливаются разные самостоятельно.

Comment: Подозреваю, что нельзя...

Comment: @Qwertiy меня бы даже устроил какой-нибудь флаг. Хотя-бы для собственного использования.

Answer (score 1):

#### Только для личного использования и непреодолимого желания быстрого доступа к меню.

На этой [устаревшей странице](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/developers/design-documents/extensions/proposed-changes/apis-under-development/context-menu-api?mobile=true) сказано:

> - Элементы расширения отображаются в нижней части контекстного меню над «Inspect element», отсортированные по имени расширения.
> - Если расширение добавляет более 1 элемента, мы автоматически помещаем эти элементы в подменю.
> - Слева от элемента верхнего уровня появится значок расширения.

Это оставляет последнюю возможность - **создать несколько** расширений **ради одного** меню:

- Основное **Master** - включает в себя управление **slave** расширениями
- Зависимые **Slave** - всего несколько строк кода для пунктов(*он может быть один*) и взаимодействия с **master**

#### Проблема сортировки/именования элементов

На самом деле сортировка зависит не от имени расширения, а от пункта меню. Имя расширения используется при группировке, когда верхний уровень становится полем `name` манифеста. Таким образом, расширение для подгрупп приходится именовать желаемым именем группы.

С другой строны, стандартное использование `contextMenus`, не позволяет установить несколько иконок. С несколькими мы получаем свободу установки иконок верхнего уровня - куда'ж без дизайна.

#### Enable/Disable ...

**...** только одним ведущим Master(*это когда на вкладке расширений мы кликаем на отключить*) достигается с помощью:

- [chrome.management.setEnabled(...)](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/management/#method-setEnabled) - при включении **master** вызываем сразу все **slave**
- [chrome.management.onDisabled.addListener(...)](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/management/#event-onDisabled) - проверяем когда отключается **master** из **slave** и сами себя выключаем

#### Взаимодействие | [Long-lived connections](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/#connect)

- [chrome.runtime.onConnectExternal.addListener( port )](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#event-onConnectExternal) - при запуске **master** устанавливаем слушателя для запроса "долгоживущих" портов от **slave**
- `port =` [chrome.runtime.connect(...)](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#method-connect) - получаем порт от **master**

Порты "живут" до выключения **master** и кроме `port.onMessage()` и `port.postMessage()` больше особо ничего не надо. Вся задача соединения послать `click` и `checked` от **slave** и получить `enabled:true|false` от **master**.

#### Результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

#### Минусы

- На странице chrome://extensions/ будет беспорядок - особо туда лазить необходимости нет.
- Подбор имен для сортировки.

#### Плюсы

- Установка иконок для всех пунктов верхнего уровня, что нельзя сделать для сгруппированного меню.
- Желаемый быстрый доступ в один клик без раздражающих переходов.